# Error de index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, numpy, data

En análisis de datos, existe un array X ∈ RN×W, donde N son las filas que corresponden a  los samples, la última columna (a la derecha) corresponde al label de cada sample, y las columnas restantes corresponden a los features.

Estoy definiendo una función, en donde el array solo tiene labels {0,1}, donde dé como resultado una matrix que solo contenga samples con label 1 y no tenga valores negativos en su primer feature, es decir:

ejemplo de dataset:

```
array([[0.5, 0.2, 0.3, -0.5, 0],
       [-0.05, 0.6, 0.35, 1.2, 1],
       [0.2, -0.2, 0.6, 2.3, 0],
       [1.7, 0.8, 0.02, 4.3, 1]
       [3.2, 1.5, 0.1, 0.3, 1]])

Matriz que debe deveolver:
array([[1.7, 0.8, 0.02, 4.3, 1]
       [3.2, 1.5, 0.1, 0.3, 1]])
```

Para ello tengo mi siguiente funcion

```
def preprocessing_matrix(samples, labels):

    import numpy as np

    # create a 2D array
    samples = np.array(samples)

    # get rows that meet the condition
    try:
      labels = samples[:, -1]
      features = samples[:, 0]
      new_matrix = samples[(features >= 0) & (labels == 1)]
    except IndexError:
      pass

    return new_matrix
```

Pero, al momento de hacer pruebas me retorna un error
index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
Pueden ayudarme por favor, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = ([
    [0.5, 0.2, 0.3, -0.5, 0],
    [-0.05, 0.6, 0.35, 1.2, 1],
    [0.2, -0.2, 0.6, 2.3, 0],
    [1.7, 0.8, 0.02, 4.3, 1],
    [3.2, 1.5, 0.1, 0.3, 1]
])



def preprocessing_matrix( matriz ):
    salida = []
    for arr in matriz:
        if( arr[ 0 ] >= 0 and arr[ len( arr ) - 1 ] == 1 ):
            salida.append( arr )
    return salida
    
print( preprocessing_matrix( array ))
```

devuelve -> [[1.7, 0.8, 0.02, 4.3, 1], [3.2, 1.5, 0.1, 0.3, 1]]

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

También puedes usar compresión de listas..

```
def preprocessing_matrix( matriz ):
    salida = [arr for arr in matriz if( arr[ 0 ] >= 0 and arr[ len( arr ) - 1 ] == 1 )]
    return salida
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. El problema es que me piden sacar la función en base a samples y labels, es decir def preprocessing_matrix(samples, labels) :(. Cómo podría hacer en ese caso?

Comment: cuales serían los valores que le pasas a la función ( samples y labels ) ?.

Comment: Si, esos son los valores, samples y labels

Comment: son objetos lo que estás pasando?

Comment: si, son objectos

Comment: para poder entender la dimensión del problema, necesitamos conocer esos objetos...

Comment: Ya pude encontrar la solución este problema era de la siguiente manera 
def preprocessing_matrix(samples, labels):
    import numpy as np

    arr = np.append(samples, labels, axis=1)
    m = arr[arr[:,0]>=0]
    matrix_f = m[m[:, -1] == 1]
    
    return matrix_f

Comment: Gracias igual por la ayuda, me sirvió bastante

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado, sería bueno que subieras tu respuesta y la marques como aceptada (obviamente tienes que desmarcar la mía), para que de esa manera, tu trabajo pueda servir a otros. gracias!!.